# Не могу понять почему не вызывается функция. Я объявил функцию, но код, записанный в функции не выполняется

Tags: c++

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <clocale>

using namespace std;

void someFunc(int Var1)
{
    int nDivision = 1000, preResult = 0, minusVar = 0, nResult = 0, d = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        preResult = Var1 / nDivision;
        nDivision = nDivision / 10;
        minusVar = nResult * 10;
        nResult = preResult - minusVar;

        cout << d
             << "\n-е число равно"
             << nResult
             << "\n";
        d++;
    }
}

int main(int args, char* pszArgs[])
{
    cout << "Введите пятизначное число\n";
    int nFive;
    cin >> nFive;
    void someFunc(int nFive);
    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `void someFunc(int nFive);` - это вы так функцию вызвать пытаетесь?

Comment: А ведь достаточно открыть *любой* учебник по C++, найти главу по функциям, и посмотреть как они вызывают функцию. Затем посмотреть на свой код и найти ровно 2 отличия.

Comment: Уберите 

    void someFunc(int nFive);

Просто пропишите

    someFunc(int nFive);

Это невнимательность)

Comment: @АндрейСаламов, Вы близки, но правильного варианта не достигли ;)

Comment: @ixSci да, опять таки невнимательность)

Comment: Опять эта загадочная мешанина из хедеров: `<stdio.h>`, но при этом вдруг `<clocale>`...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Не могу понять почему не вызывается функция. Я объявил функцию, но код, записанный в функции не выполняется

Вызывать функцию: `your_func_name(your_param)`, это ваш случай.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <clocale>

using namespace std;

void someFunc(int Var1)
{
    int nDivision = 1000, preResult = 0, minusVar = 0, nResult = 0, d = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        preResult = Var1 / nDivision;
        nDivision = nDivision / 10;
        minusVar = nResult * 10;
        nResult = preResult - minusVar;

        cout << d
             << "\n-е число равно"
             << nResult
             << "\n";
        d++;
    }
}

int main(int args, char* pszArgs[])
{
    cout << "Введите пятизначное число\n";
    int nFive;
    cin >> nFive;
    someFunc(nFive); // <-- Вот так вызывается
    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно заменить    `void someFunc(int nFive);`
на `someFunc(int nFive);` иначе вы пытаетесь объявить прототип этой функции, но никак не вызвать её.

Comment: Можно ведь при написании ответа проявить внимательность и дать правильный? Тем более, что правильный ответ уже есть.